# After Unity Builds(Jumbo Builds) apply into our project, lib size is decreased but dll size is same. Why nothing change?

Tags: c++

The amount of code in our C++ project is too much.

The compilation time is too long and the module size is too large.

After some research, we know 3 ways of reducing C/C++ build time.

1. Money
2. Use import instead of #include (Supported since C++ 17)
3. Use Unity build (another name 'Unified build', 'Jumbo build' etc..)

We applied unity build to our project.

Build time has been reduced by half and .lib file size has been reduced by 276.708 MByte. But .dll file size was same.

Please provide a clear answer. Thank you :)

Comment: *"In Windows, there are two types of library, a static library and an import library (both confusingly use the .lib extension, however)."* So, which .lib do you talk? and why do you expect (significative) smaller dll?

Comment: *"import instead of #include"* is an upcoming C++20 feature and it won't really increase compilation speed that much. If you want a clear answer then you should post a more detailed problem description. For example how may files does this project have, how many translation units, how many external libraries are linked in, what was initial size of the library, what are the sizes of the linked libraries etc. What if you are linking something like CEF and expect dll size reduction all of it sudden? *"Build time has been reduced by half"* seems to be a suspiciously insignificant gain.

Comment: " But .dll file size was same." you still have symbols from `.hpp` files correct? Jumbo only simplifies by applying all implementations in one huge translation unit, the `.o` file which will be a `.dll` or `.so` shall be the same size, just linkage is simplified.